# What does s=' ' mean in the string concatenation method of solving FizzBuzz?

Tags: python

What does `s=''` mean in the string concatenation method of solving FizzBuzz?

```
for i in range (1,101):
    s='' # what does this mean?
    if i%3==0:
        s=s+'Fizz' # what does it mean by adding empty string to 'Fizz'?
    if i%5==0:
        s=s+'Buzz'
    if i%5!=0 and i%3!=0:
        s=s+str(i) # why is s=''necessary for FizzBuzz to be displayed?
    print(s)
```

Comment: `''` is an empty string.

Comment: It sets the variable `s` to an empty string. And it's not `' '`. It's `''`. Different.

Comment: `s=''` is initializing the variable `s` to an empty string. In the code `s=s+'Fizz'` since `s` is an empty string, it translates to `s=''+'Fizz'` which is the same as `s='Fizz'`

Answer (score 1):

`s=''` is initializing the variable `s` to an empty string. In the code `s=s+'Fizz'` since `s` is an empty string, it translates to `s=''+'Fizz'` which is the same as `s='Fizz'` in this case. The main reason you are initializing `s=''` is because this code runs in a loop, so without resetting the value of `s` the previous values would remain.

Answer (score 0):

When you declared `s=''` it was assigning an empty string to variable s. `s=''` is just defining variable `s` so you can use it in later code.